# How to deploy adobe AIR application

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have to create an application which has to read some files from the local system. As the FileSystem classes are availabe only in the AIR applications I created it as AIR application. But after publishing, the exe is not working. How can I make it working?

Comment: What do you mean 'is not working'? Is there any error?

Comment: And which IDE do you use? Flash Develop, FlashBuilder, IntelliJ IDEA or FlashCS?

Comment: You point a magic wand at it and say _abra kadabra, alakazam_ with emphasis on the _zam_ in _alakazam_ and hey presto, it'll begin working

Answer (score 0):

Might help you....
http://permadi.com/blog/2011/06/creating-air-based-android-application-using-flash-ide/